# Is there Box rest api to fetch folders connected to a user?

Tags: box

Below rest `api` provides the membership details of a box user:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/users/335014321/memberships
```

Is there a similar `api` that will fetch folders connected to box user?

I have tried below rest endpoint but gave response `status`:

```
405,"code":"method_not_allowed".
```

https://api.box.com/2.0/users/335014321/folders

Answer (score 0):

You would probably not be able to get the folders connected to a box user without the oauth token from that user.

If you are an admin of a box enterprise account. You can use the As-User header. You can take a look at this

https://box-content.readme.io/reference#as-user-1

You would have to get an access token as an admin to be able to use the As-User call as well as sending a Support Ticket to Box Support to ask them to activate your application to allow the usage of As-User.